# Powe BI Email Subscription

Tags: powerbi

Good day!

I'm trying to allow my customers to subscribe to my power bi dashboards to receive a summary email periodically.

My question is: is power bi desktop version needs to be installed on their machiens?

They already have accounts to access the dashboard in the portal where i upload the dashboards but not all of them installed the desktop version.

I tried to search on power bi community but I didn't find an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, desktop is not required to be installed on their PCs if they are just consuming a report via the Power BI portal, or via email subscription. desktop is only required for people creating reports.